# DLL file could not be located when loading RStudio

Tags: r, dll, rstudio

I got this message after installing the latest R and RStudio and trying to load RStudio:

> Procedure Entry Point modf could not be found in dynamic link library in qt5positioning.dll

I tried to solve by update the latest Windows but still cannot. Checked that the DLL files are in my System file already.

Some more details:

- Studio Edition: Desktop
- RStudio Version: RStudio 1.2.1335
- OS Version: Windows 8.1
- R Version: R 3.6.1

Comment: Have you looked to see others who might have had this error and how they fixed it

Comment: Can you try and older version, sometime between 2013 and 2016 when your OS was still current?